# Displaying files in terminal line by line?

Tags: bash, terminal, command

Is is possible, in terminal, to ls command a folder and view each file line by line instead of just spanning across horizontally?

Normal Display:

---

Assignment10.py Assignment12.py Excercise01.py  Excercise03.py  Excercise05.py  Excercise07.py  Excercise09.py  README.txt
Assignment11.py Assignment13.py Excercise02.py  Excercise04.py  Excercise06.py  Excercise08.py  Excercise14.py  Template.py
Ryans-MacBook-Pro-2:Learn_Python_The_Hard_Way_Excercises rschacht$

Preferred Display:

---

Assignment10.py

Excercise03.py
Excercise05.py
Excercise07.py
Excercise09.py
README.txt

Comment: `ls -1`? you should have tried `man ls` to see what IS available...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ls` is capable of doing that:

`ls -1`

(that's a one)

Comment: Literally perfect, thanks a lot. I will vote your answer when timer is up in 10 mins.

Comment: Can you explain the -1 and why something like -2 doesn't work?

Comment: @Simplex `-1` is a commandline option, like `-s` or `-h`. The one is arbitrary in this case, not an integer argument. As Marc B points out in your question, checkout `man ls` for all of the options you can give to `ls`.